# Excluding fields in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-ee-6

I have 2 classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A {

    private Long id;
    private B b;

    // setters and getters
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
public class B {

    private Long id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    // setters and getters
}
```

By default, if I transform an instance of class `A` to the XML, I will have all its fields (`id`) and the referenced `B` class fields (`id`, `field1`, `field2`) like this:

```
<a>
    <id>2</id>
    <b>
        <id>5</id>
        <field1>test1</field1>
        <field2>test3</field2>
    </b>
</a>
```

Is is possible to modify **what** fields from referenced class `B` are included in the XML of the `A` class? E.g. I want to say that when I transform an instance of `A` class, I just want to get `id` from the `B` class (no `field1` and `field2` fields), so I want to get:

```
<a>
    <id>2</id>
    <b>
        <id>5</id>
    </b>
</a>
```

I don't want to permanently annotate the `B` class (using `@XMLTransient` or `@XMLElement`) to achieve it, as there are cases in which I want to export whole `B` class as is (with `id`, `field1` and `field2`.)
I just don't want to export all these fields when the `B` class is referenced from `A`.

Is this even possible with JAX-B?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) on the field. Also the default JAXB bindings can be overridden at a global scope or on a case-by-case basis as needed by using [custom binding declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).

Check out the [Guide to JAXB](http://www.baeldung.com/jaxb) from Baeldung website for more examples.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it complicates things a bit if I'm using Glassfish JAXB implementation... It seems that there is no annotation-based solution and I need to create an additional customization XML?

Answer (score 108):

You can use annotation `@XmlTransient` to ignore fields. Put this annotation on field itself or its getter.

Comment: Where should I put it? On the `B` class `field1` and `field2` fields? Wouldn't it cause to remove the `field1` and `field2` from occurring when transforming **an instance of `B` class**?

Comment: You should put these annotations on fields or methods of class B. Fields of will not be removed. They just will not appear in resulting XML

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I think it's exactly the thing I don't want to do (please refer to the last paragraph of my question). This change will forbid the fields from appearing in resulting XML in **all occurrences** of B class.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I've come up with some hacky solution:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A {

    private Long id;
    private B b;

    // setters and getters
}
```

I've provided an additional getter just for the REST use case, so it's like:

```
@XMLTransient
public B getB() {
    return b;
}

@XMLElement(name="b")
public Long getBForREST() {
    return b.getId();
}
```

It results in the following structure:

```
<a>
    <id>2</id>
    <b>5</b>
</a>
```

It's not exactly same structure I aimed for it works for me.

I don't like this solution - an `@XMLExclude({"field1", "field2"})` or something like that would be much cleaner in my opinion.

Nevertheless - for now on, it works; it's ugly, but it works.

Comment: You can even make the REST-only getter private, so it won't confuse users of your class.